# Why can't I find any information about object STRUCTURE in Locals window?

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I have been trying to understand all of the properties that I see listed in the Locals window in VBE.

Why do some objects have infinitely nested, identical properties? The Range object has a Cells property, which has a Cells property, which has a Cells property, which has a Cells property............ You get the point.

What is this and what is its purpose? Why is it so hard to find the fields that actually CONTAIN the information I'm looking for?

There's an application property of the Range object. You can also find an identical application property as a sublistings of other properties. Why? Are they the same reference? If there are, then why obfuscate the information by putting it there repeatedly? If it's not the same reference then what is it?

I'm looking at the Range Object so I can try find the current region the range encompasses. currentRegion has a currentRegion.....which has a currentRegion.....which has currentRegion.....

currentRegion property, Areas property? No information given on what the difference is between these two and they are synonyms.  If the Range.Address properpty exists and it's a simple object type, then why are these other two more complicated?

All I want to do is be able to create an object.....and then actually see what that object is and its values. if anyone can give me some more information, or rather can point me in the direction of documentation that explains this stuff I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: `Cells` returns a `Range` object. `CurrentRegion` also returns a `Range` object. `Range.Address` returns a `String`. You might start with the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel)?

Comment: Object Browser might not be a great way to learn about high-level concepts in Excel VBA.  It's useful for referencing certain odd things but the docs (or a actual book!) would be more effective.

Comment: ...and you'll often find object relationships work both ways: eg a `Worksheet` has `Range` items, but every `Range` object also has a `Worksheet` property.   If you end up navigating back up the hierarchy to `Application` then of course you can go anywhere from there.

Comment: Wait….. they’re all links to the same object? Then why would they display it as if there was a parent-child relationship? Ugh that makes so much sense why would they not make that more obvious? I’m struggling to understand how having a link back from EVERY step  helps enough to offset how much bloat is in the object?

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, it's not really clear what you are asking. And this is not an answer, but it's too long for a comment.

So okay, lets do an example. A `Range` represents one or several cell(s) of an Excel worksheet. Lots of properties are obvious: `Value` represents the stored value of the cells, `Address` the address, `Interior` with its properties things that define how a cell looks like (color, border...).
Now a cell has a property `CurrentRegion`. `CurrentRegion` is a handy property that tells you the surrounding block of cells that contain data. But `CurrentRegion` is a group of cells and, as we learned, a group of cell is represented as `Range`. With other words, `CurrentRegion` is a `Range`-property of a `Range`, and therefore has itself a property `CurrentRegion`. Why not? And what would be the alternative? A class `RangeButNotWithCurrentRegion`? Or would you set the property `CurrentRegion` to `Nothing` if it is the property of a Range that is already used as `CurrentRegion`? What sense would this make?
The `Cells`-property of a Range is simply a collection of all cells of that Range. You can address single cells of a `Range` by either use a single index (`Cells(10)` would represent the 10th cell within that range) or by using row and column as index (`Cells(3, 10)` is the cell at row 3 and column 10 of that Range). And again, a single cell is a `Range` and therefore has a property `Cells` (and, surprise, a property `CurrentRegion`). Again: What would be the alternative: A class `RangeButWithoutCells`?

Another example: The topmost class in VBA is the `Application`-object. In Excel, the `Application`-object has a `Collection` named `Workbooks` that is a list of all open Workbooks. Now every `Workbook` has a property `Application` that points back to exactly this `Application`-object. Why is it? Sometimes that's handy, for example if you are using *Excel*-Objects within a *Word*-VBA macro. And if you think it's superfluent, just forget about it. Don't use it. Until one bright day you *will* use it and be thankfull that it's there.

If you are looking for the exact information about an object, you can start at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel). And while it's far from perfect, it holds a lot of information that you need. Or press F2 in the VBE to open the object browser. Or put the cursor on a keyword in the code editor (eg `CurrentRegion`) and press F1 to jump to the official documentation for that class/property. Or search on SO. Or use the search engine of your choice (I will *not* give the advice to use ChatGPT...)

**Update** The *locals* window and it's counterpart, the *watch* window, are excellent starting points to explore an object, so I guess you are on a good way. If you find something that you already saw (like a `CurrentRegion`-property of a `CurrentRegion`-property), just stop clicking on it, it will give you no more information. The `Application`-Object will always be the same object, and it makes no sense to click on it recursively until the VBE dies an OutOfMemory or StackOverflow error). Just learn that for lots of object, you can go down *and* up the hierachy.
And be aware that not all properties are displayed in the Local window or the object browser. There are *hidden* properties that are not listed, but you can use them anyhow.

Comment: I should clarify that my problem is not fundamental understanding. I didn’t articulate that very well. I do understand the concept of ranges and cells(although thank you for mentioning the official documentation. I had looked at it but missed the properties at the bottom so I can get an explanation of each one). 

That wasn’t really my  main issue though. I’m not sure how I’m supposed to respond with such limited characters but I’ll give it a try. 

I was using the locals window to debug my code. I had a previously instantiated object someohow disappear and I was trying to step through

Comment: I was trying to locate the correct attributes and check but then I ran into this problem. Ignoring comprehension of what the fields do themselves, how am I supposed to know what they are?

Why would I want a path back up from EVERY object? Why would they design a system that would let me endlessly dive into an infinite nest until I ran out of memory? 

Ok so every object has an application as a super. I get that even if I dislike the bloat it puts in the window. 

But how could properties have an endless list of the same thing? Where are all these other objects that are being referenced

Comment: Cells aren’t a subclass of cells and it makes no logical sense for a cell object to have another cell object as an attribute, so why is it linked in such a way to imply it’s a direct descendant? And if it’s referencing a static method why would it show up in the object itself as if it were a fundamental field?

Comment: There is no `Cell` class in the Excel object model, because a `Range` has exactly all the same properties as a single cell. So a `Range` object has a `Cells` property that just returns itself, and that property is of type `Range`.. and you can drill down as infinitum that way, because there's a disconnect between the truth and your understanding of the object model you're looking at. At the end of the day an object property returns a pointer/reference to an object; in the case of the Excel object model everything is owned and defined by Excel.

Comment: The Excel object model indeed starts at `Application`, and for convenience it was decided that every object in the model would hold a reference to both its parent, and to the root `Application` instance. That's just a design decision you can agree or disagree with, but it's not a bug in the VBIDE. The locals toolwindow actually starts falling apart when you have an object that `Implements` an interface, but that's another thing entirely.

Comment: To further clarify, I understand the functional reason for having links back to the application. 

But WHY would anyone possibly care to see all those links from an organizational perspective? I opened the locals window to see information about the object and there’s more dead space than anything else. What benefit could it possibly be just to KNOW that the link exists? How does that help me if my intent is to monitor? It’s not like I’m actually coding at that point so why would I care to know that link exists? Either I’m using it or I’m not.

Comment: Yes there is clearly a disconnect at play here. I just don’t understand what I don’t understand. This object model doesn’t seem complex enough for it to be this confusing to look at. Right I understand what you mean about object pointers, but I don’t have infinite objects? What object could it possibly be pointing at endlessly? Are you telling me it’s making a new object everytime I open a new sub object? Or it’s just making a new reference? To an object that doesn’t exist yet? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: _but I don’t have infinite objects?_ indeed you don't! I'd recommend writing classes yourself to better grasp what's going on and what you're looking at. Make a new class and call it `Class1` and write `Public Something As Class1` in there, then `Public Foo As Long`; now add a `Sub Test` in a standard module `Module1`, and do `Set obj1 = New Class1` and `Set obj2 = New Class1`, and then do `obj1.Foo = 42` and `obj2.Foo = 10`, and `Set obj1.Something = obj1`, and then `Set obj2.Something = obj1` also. Then run it and again but set it to `obj2` and see how it changes the toolwindow.